# SQL Server on Mac with Docker : Login failed for user 'password too short'

Tags: sql-server, docker, passwords

I am trying very simply to download MS SQL Server to my Mac using Docker.

As I was following a video, I reached a road block because my password was too short and Docker exits the program. (I received the error below). Can you please advise on how to change my password using the terminal or elsewhere?

ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is too short.

Comment: did you try to provide longer password?

Comment: how do i provide a longer pw is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container only accepts SQL auth and you've locked yourself out by making SQL auth impossible for the only SQL auth account that exists. Kind of a catch-22 because you can't log in to make your password long enough so that you can log in. I wish docker recognized this when you first fire up the `run` command instead of when it is too late, but this is where we are.

While it may be possible to hack into `mssql-conf` or the `mssql-server` service to change the password, honestly, the easiest thing for you to do is to start over with a new container. The nice thing about containers is that this is exactly what they're designed for. Run this:

```
docker ps
```

This will list the containers you have created; the one in question might be named something like `a5de64...`, so then just do:

```
docker stop a5
docker rm a5
```

Then create a new container with a password that is both long enough and strong enough:

```
docker run ... -e SA_PASSWORD=d0_n0t_be_l@zy_h3r3 ... mcr.microsoft...
```